# Showing all records in JOIN clause in database

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables, named `voter` and `log_vote`. `Voter` contains data of voters while `log_vote` contains data of voters who have voted.

Now I'm trying to show the voters **who haven't voted**. I have tried using JOIN in both tables but it will fail since JOIN clause only shows voters that have voted of course.

Here's the code snippet which I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM voter INNER JOIN log_vote ON log_vote.nim = voter.nim
```

How to show only voters who haven't voted? Is using JOIN a correct way to do? Thanks in advance, I will really appreciate for the answer!

*NOTE: I'm using PHP Technology. Wonder if there's any way that PHP can do with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a LEFT JOIN, that way the join condition won't filter those who dont answer it, and then you filter all those who didn't have a match like this:

```
SELECT voter.* FROM voter
LEFT JOIN log_vote ON log_vote.nim = voter.nim
WHERE log_vote.nim is null
```

Comment: Solved and pretty simple. Thank you!

Comment: No problem @AlvianCasablancas :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the most direct method is `not exists`:

```
select v.*
from voter v
where not exists (select 1 from log_vote lv where lv.nim = v.nim);
```

If you want to use `join`, then the appropriate version is `left join`:

```
select v.*
from voter v left join
     log_vote lv
     on lv.nim = v.nim
where lv.nim is null;
```

Comment: It works. Btw, what do v and lv mean? Why it can be used for replacing `voter` and `log_voter`?

Comment: @AlvianCasablancas . . . They are called table aliases.  They are abbreviations for the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also..

```
SELECT * FROM voter LEFT JOIN log_vote ON log_vote.nim = voter.nim 
WHERE log_vote.nim IS NULL
```

Comment: Can also do this? both me and gordon posted this answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use

> NOT IN

this code should work!

> SELECT * FROM voter v WHERE v.nim NOT IN (SELECT lv.nim FROM log_vote lv)

you should give more information about the attribute of each tables are you sure they have the attribute nim in each?

Comment: Yes, the `nim` is the primary key.
Just testing it, and it shows error for 'lv.nim' column.